# Passing exceptions in Airflow

Tags: exception, airflow

I am new to Apache Airflow, and I plan to run Python and R script files using the BashOperator class.  I want to understand how Exceptions should work in two situations:
1. The R or Python script fails for some reason; or
2. The R or Python script completes but I want to require human input before the DAG proceeds to the next task.

I have two very basic questions:
1. How does an Exception get passed from an R or Python script file to the BashOperator to the DAG?  For example, should the call to an R script file be inside a try block in the BashOperator?
2. How do I pass a custom exception (warning? error?) so that even if the R or Python script completes successfully, I can pause execution of the DAG?

I'd appreciate any examples of Airflow exception handling that you could point me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget that you are using any Airflow operators.

Just say you are writing a Bash Script that runs the R or Python script.

**Case 1**: Bash Script that fails if Python Script fails:

```
set -e
python test_file.py
```

**Case 2**: Bash Script that passes even if Python Script fails:

```
python test_file.py || exit 0
```

Now just pass one of the above bash scripts in BashOperator.

Basically, `BashOperator` just runs normal Bash commands/script and passes the logs and exit status of the Script. In Case 1 your Airflow task would also fail and in case 2 the Airflow task would fail.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  So 'set -e' exits if the command fails, and '|| exit 0' passes anyway if the script's exit status is non-zero.  You wrote that the BashOperator "passes the logs and exit status"--how do you access those inside the DAG?  And in case 2, would "0" be the only information that got passed?  Or how would I pass a warning like "Check result before continuing?"

Comment: The BashOperators would log entire stdout. If you pass `xcom_push=True`, the last line written to stdout will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes. This can be accessed in the next downstream task using Xcom Pull. Example: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py